# Ruby Pascal's triangle generator with memoization

Tags: ruby, closures, memoization

I am attempting to memoize my implementation of a Pascal's triangle generator, as a Ruby learning experiment.  I have the following working code:

```
module PascalMemo
  @cache = {}
  def PascalMemo::get(r,c)
    if @cache[[r,c]].nil? then 
      if c == 0 || c == r then 
        @cache[[r,c]] = 1
      else
        @cache[[r,c]] = PascalMemo::get(r - 1, c) + PascalMemo::get(r - 1, c - 1)
      end
    end
    @cache[[r,c]]
  end
end

def pascal_memo (r,c)
  PascalMemo::get(r,c)
end
```

Can this be made more concise?  Specifically, can I create a globally-scoped function with a local closure more simply than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def pascal_memo
  cache = [[1]]
  get = lambda { |r, c|
    ( cache[r] or cache[r] = [1] + [nil] * (r - 1) + [1] )[c] or
      cache[r][c] = get.(r - 1, c) + get.(r - 1, c - 1)
  }
end

p = pascal_memo
p.( 10, 7 ) #=> 120
```

Please note that the above construct does achieve memoization, it is not just a simple recursive method.

Comment: I learned a lot from this.  I didn't want to leave behind the `pascal_memo` factory function, but I was able to achieve this by making the factory function a lambda itself, and assigning `p` to the result of calling it inline.  The `.(r,c)` syntactic sugar was also new to me.  Finally, the function itself is clever in how it builds the cache - although in this it sacrifices quite a bit of readability :(

Comment: I'm glad it helped. As for cache building, I just tried to come up with an alternative. Note that the cache itself gets built in a local variable stored in the lambda's binding, not in main.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be made more concise?

It seems pretty clear, IMO, and `module`ing is usually a good instinct.

> can I create a globally-scoped function with a local closure more simply than this?

Another option would be a recursive `lambda`:

```
memo = {}

pascal_memo = lambda do |r, c|
  if memo[[r,c]].nil?
    if c == 0 || c == r
      memo[[r,c]] = 1
    else
      memo[[r,c]] = pascal_memo[r - 1, c] + pascal_memo[r - 1, c - 1]
    end
  end
  memo[[r,c]]
end

pascal_memo[10, 2]
# => 45
```

Comment: If I may ask, `@cache` instance variable belongs to what object?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: good catch, that was a copy-paste holdover. No need for the instance variable at all

Comment: This was useful, as I did not know how to create a recursive lambda.  However, I accepted the other answer, as it did not leave the cache in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to accomplish what I want that is slightly more satisfactory, since it produces a function rather than a lambda:

```
class << self
  cache = {}

  define_method :pascal_memo do |r,c|
    cache[[r,c]] or 
    (if c == 0 or c == r then cache[[r,c]] = 1 else nil end) or 
    cache[[r,c]] = pascal_memo(r-1,c) + pascal_memo(r-1,c-1)
  end
end
```

This opens up the metaclass/singleton class for the main object, then uses define_method to add a new method that closes over the cache variable, which then falls out of scope for everything except the pascal_memo method.